# How can I make a regex pattern with predefined character classes and lookahead?

Tags: regex, pattern-matching, regex-lookarounds

```
String search1 = "protected List<abDTO.bdDTO.cd> name;"
String search2 = "protected List<abDTO.bd.cd> name;"
```

I like to replace the classnames which has no DTO.

Result:

```
String res1= "protected List<abDTO.bdDTO.cdDTO> name;"
String res2= "protected List<abDTO.bdDTO.cdDTO> name;"
```

At the end I hat something like that with java:

```
.replaceAll("DTO\\.(\\w+)(?!DTO)\\>", "DTO.$1DTO>")
.replaceAll("DTO\\.(\\w+)(?!DTO)\\.", "DTO.$1DTO>")
```

I think I'm not far from the result.

How can I combine the predefined character classe `\w` and to tell them, that it can't contain DTO at the end of the word?

Comment: Is it Java? Please tag it.

Comment: It is not quite clear. Do you mean to match `List<xxxDTO.` and then add `DTO` to each element inside the angle brackets? See [`s.replaceAll("(\\G(?!^)\\.|List<\\w*DTO\\.)(\\w*?)(?:DTO)?(?=[>.])", "$1$2DTO")`](https://regex101.com/r/cK67yI/1).